# Why don't EclipseLinkConnectionHandle implement the releaseConnection method?

Tags: eclipselink

In DefaultJpaDialect.releaseJdbcConnection(), the doc said that:
"This implementation does nothing, assuming that the Connection will implicitly be closed with the EntityManager.

If the JPA implementation returns a Connection handle that it expects the application to close after use, the dialect implementation needs to invoke Connection.close() (or some other method with similar effect) here."

In EclipseLinkJpaDialect.getJdbcConnection(), it returns the EclipseLinkConnectionHandle.
However there seems no implementation codes for releaseConnection in EclipseLinkConnectionHandle.

```
    private static class EclipseLinkConnectionHandle implements ConnectionHandle {

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    private Connection connection;

    public EclipseLinkConnectionHandle(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (this.connection == null) {
            this.connection = this.entityManager.unwrap(Connection.class);
        }
        return this.connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(Connection con) {
    }
}
```

In this case, how to close the opened connections? or how connections closed?

Comment: I think you misunderstood what the docs were saying, as it seems to be saying the EntityManager itself will close the connection when the context is closed. The code you've shown isn't opening a new connection, it is only returning the one the EntityManager is using and responsible for, so it would be handled the same way as if you didn't have a handle to the connection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Maybe I need to clarify my question in another way: I always receive the error that FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already, However if check with postgresql, i'll see most of sessions in the idle state? why don't the eclipselink jpa reuse the idle connection instead of throw the error that too many clients?

Comment: I don't know, it would depend on your connection pooling options.  I'd recommend turning logging to finest as well to show when connections are being obtained in your application.